# Is there any word for a person who doesn't want to connect with others?

Tags: nouns

What is a word to say someone who doesn't want to connect any person and likes to avoid social interactions?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *connect* in this instance?

Comment: A "DMV clerk" ?

Comment: Anyone who's spoken to me for more than five minutes. *hangs head in shame*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In our neighborhood, we refer to a person like this as a *[hermit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hermit)*:

> noun
>
> 1.0 A person living in solitude as a religious discipline.
>
> 1.1 A reclusive or solitary person.

The synonym *[troglodyte](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/troglodyte)* has broader connotations.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps [**asocial**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/asocial):

> Avoiding social interaction; inconsiderate of or hostile to others

Or [**loner**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/loner):

> A person who prefers not to associate with others.

Or [**Reclusive**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/reclusive):

> Avoiding the company of other people; solitary.

Answer (score 5):

A *[recluse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recluse)* would behave like this:

> noun
>
> A person who lives a solitary life and tends to avoid other people:

Answer (score 1):

One could view this behavior as a symptom of *[misanthropy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/misanthropy)*:

> noun
>
> hatred of mankind, antisocial behaviour, cynicism, scepticism,
> reclusiveness

The person would be called a ***misanthrope***.

Comment: A misanthrope just hates people. Doesn't mean the misanthrope doesn't want to connect with people. Exhibit A: the [Hedgehog's Dilemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog%27s_dilemma). Or, put another way.. A misanthrope hates humanity. But that doesn't mean they *want* to hate humanity; they might want that hatred to be proven unjustified, and to accomplish that disproof through interaction.

Answer (score 0):

If they have a Christian religious motivation, someone like this might be from one of the isolation sects:

*[Anchorite](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anchorite)*

*[Cenobite](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cenobite)*

*[Eremite](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eremite)*

Comment: I suppose the main reason this is unhelpful is that, if the person you're talking about is part of an obscure reclusive religious sect, you'll already know what it's called. Because that's  a major, unmissable biographical detail. And if they aren't in such a sect, the word's useless. So, either you're telling someone what they already know, or you're telling them what they don't need to know.

Comment: Thank you, @ParthianShot, for letting me know that this post didn't help you. Apparently, you have missed the point. The OP was sufficiently vague as to permit the possibility of someone stumbling upon one of these *hermits* in their own isolated space, unwilling to connect. They are *hermits* in the most general sense, but they are also a specific kind of *hermit*. E.g.: [Anchorite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchorite)

Comment: Well, sure. The OP was also sufficiently vague that he could have been referring to your friend Bob. But answering "Did you mean Bob?" is also unlikely to be helpful to anyone, hence the downvote. Historically, there have been plenty of reclusive people. Which is why we came up with general terms like "recluse", so that when someone wanted to succinctly express "doesn't like being around people", they could say "recluse" rather than saying "eremite" and handing the listener an accompanying dictionary.